# Loading view controller from storyboard objective c - keeps purging content

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I have a legacy objective c project that uses a code instantiated navigation controller, that loads other view controllers, no problems. However, due to simplicity I changed one of my tableview controllers to be in a storyboard. I load the controller from the storyboard like this:

```
UIViewController *searchViewController;
searchViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
searchViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard1" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"resultViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:searchViewController animated:YES];
```

That all works fine.

However when the user dismiss the searchViewController and wants to reinstate it, the content is completely gone and the users has to type a new search and wait for server to deliver it. This was not the case when pushed a non storyboard based view controller on to the navigation controller. Also the navigationcontroller is non-ARC whereas the new viewcontroller in the storyboard is ARC.. but indicated properly with compile time options.. kind of pulling my hair out on this one!

Comment: Short remark: I don't think storyboards are simpler than code.

Comment: Turns out that loading a NIF/XIB from a storyboard always results in a brand new object instance, thats is why the view controller is never reused. Would be nice to be able to reuse the views controller somehow.